# Python MATLAB bridge JSON error

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to use a [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)-to-[MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) bridge, and I don't know what is going on any more.

Every time I run my script I get the this error:

```
File "/Users/Casey/Desktop/ABOVE_TCP/Ingestion_software/test.py", line 8, in <module>
res = mlab.run('/Users/Casey/Desktop/ABOVE_TCP/Ingestion_software/jk.m', {'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 5, 'arg3': 4}, maxtime=20)
  File "/Users/Casey/Desktop/ABOVE_TCP/Ingestion_software/pymatbridge/__init__.py", line 85, in run
result = self._open_page(self.eval_func, page_args, maxtime)
   File "/Users/Casey/Desktop/ABOVE_TCP/Ingestion_software/pymatbridge/__init__.py", line 96, in _open_page
return json.loads(page.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 385, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Then I tried to do the basic one given on the front of the GitHub page. That worked.
I slowly copied and pasted code from the other MATLAB script untill I got to where I make the plots, and once I did that I couldn't run it any more. It just won't do it and always gives me the same error, even if I delete the plotting code.

I went in and printed out the JSON object in question, with out trying to put it through JSON, and it's the following.

```
<html><body><font color="#FF0000">Error in file : web_feval.m</font><br><br><font color="#990000"> The file returned the following error: <br>Printing of uicontrols is not supported on this platform.</font></body></html> 0
```

Where it is getting that is beyond me. I have no idea. I can run this script from MATLAB only and it's fat, dumb, and happy.

For good measure, here is both the Python and MATLAB code.

```
from pymatbridge import Matlab
import os

mlab = Matlab(matlab='/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab')
matlabStart = mlab.start()
if not os.path.isfile('/Users/Casey/Desktop/ABOVE_TCP/Ingestion_software/plot_maker.m'):
    print 'well here is your issue'
res = mlab.run('/Users/Casey/Desktop/ABOVE_TCP/Ingestion_software/jk.m', {'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 5, 'arg3': 4}, maxtime=20)

print res['result']
mlab.stop()
```

And the MATLAB code without the plotting:

```
function lol = jk(args)
    restoredefaultpath;
    clc;
    clear all;
    close all;
    clear functions;
    bdclose('all');
    fclose('all');
    arg1 = args.arg1
    arg2 = args.arg2
    arg3 = args.arg3
    fileName = '/Users/Casey/Desktop/MatlabTest/20140714_175009_cmrs_above_Full_Data.dat';
    summaryFileName =     '/Users/Casey/Desktop/MatlabTest/20140714_175009_cmrs_above_summary_plot.png';
    windowSize = 2048;
    overLap = windowSize * 0.75;
    sampleFreq = 150000;
    Window = hann(windowSize);

    dataFile = fopen(fileName);
    header = blanks(115);
    i = 1;
    %dataContents = fileread(fileName);
    dataContents = fread(dataFile);
    while i < 115
        char = dataContents(i);
        header(i) = char;
        if char == '}'
            break
        end
        i = i + 1;
    end
    header = header(2:i-1);
    headerSplit = strsplit(header,',');
    fileSize = str2double(headerSplit(17));
    fseek(dataFile, i + 0,'bof');
    Info = dir(fileName);
    Data = fread(dataFile,[Info.bytes 1], 'bit16', 0, 'b'); % Need to muliply filesize by 2 for final release
    fseek(dataFile, Info.bytes-10, 'bof');

    %Decide if end key check is needed, and what to do with it
    %endKey = textscan(dataFile, '%s');
    %endKey = endKey{1}{1};
    fclose(dataFile);

    Data = Data(1:fileSize/2);
    Chan1 = Data(1:2:end);
    Chan2 = Data(2:2:end);

    FFTChan1 = fft(Chan1, sampleFreq);
    FFTChan2 = fft(Chan2, sampleFreq);

    %iniliaze vectors for the polarizations
    LHC = zeros(length(FFTChan1),1);
    RHC = zeros(length(FFTChan1),1);
    TP = zeros(length(FFTChan1),1);


    for i = 1:length(FFTChan1)
        TP(i) = abs(FFTChan1(i))+abs(FFTChan2(i));
        RHC(i) = real(FFTChan1(i))+imag(FFTChan2(i));
        LHC(i) =real(FFTChan1(i))-imag(FFTChan2(i));
    end

    TPS = ifft(TP);
    RHCS = ifft(RHC);
    LHCS = ifft(LHC);
    maxTime = (length(Chan1)-1)/sampleFreq;


    lol = 'YYYUUUUUPPPPP';
    %lol = arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
end
```

And now for the plotting.

```
    %start making the plots!
    %set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off');
    %subplot(3,1,1);
    %spectrogram(TPS, Window, overLap,windowSize, sampleFreq, 'yaxis');
    %colorbar;
    %axis([0 maxTime 0 75000]);
    %title('Total Power');
    %subplot(3,1,2);
    %spectrogram(LHCS, Window, overLap,windowSize, sampleFreq, 'yaxis');
    %colorbar;
    %axis([0 maxTime 0 75000]);
    %title('Left Hand Cicular Polarization');

    %subplot(3,1,3);
    %spectrogram(RHCS, Window, overLap, windowSize, sampleFreq, 'yaxis')
    %colorbar;
    %axis([0 maxTime 0 75000]);
    %title('Right Hand Ciruclar Polarization');
    %saveas(1,summaryFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue being related to the figure created by the `spectrogram` function. By specifying an output, you could use the `spectrogram` function just to calculate the short-time Fourier transform of the signal and then create the plot (see [documentation](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html)).

After computing the transform:

```
[S,F,T] = spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,F,fs)
```

you have at least two alternatives to create the spectrogram plot: `surf`, that is the one implicitly used by `spectrogram` and `imagesc`. In the first case, you can display the plot with the following code (refer to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html#f8-808211)):

```
surf(T, F, 10*log10(abs(P)));
axis tight;
view(0, 90);
```

Using `imagesc` (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13862000/1236452) previous answer and [this](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz/issues/1#issuecomment-1930504) comment):

```
%plot the log spectrum
imagesc(T, F, log(S));

%flip the Y Axis so lower frequencies are at the bottom
set(gca, 'YDir', 'normal');
```

Comment: Sadly this has not helped. I still get the same problem. What gets me confused is even if I completely delete the plotting code it still breaks. Before I add the plotting code to a file it works just fine, but after I try it once with making a plot I have to make a new file.